# Textarea should display only whole lines in height

Tags: css, textarea

I have a component TextArea.

```
export const TextArea = styled.textarea`
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: ${style('color')};
  border-color: ${style('input.border.color')};
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: ${style('input.background')};
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: normal;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  caret-color: ${style('input.caret.color')};
  &:hover:enabled {
    border-color: ${style('input.hover.border.color')};
  }
  &:focus-visible,
  &:active:enabled {
    border-color: ${style('input.active.border.color')};
  }
  &:disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  &:focus-visible {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px ${style('focus.color')};
  }
  transition:
    box-shadow ${style('focus.transition')}s,
    border-color ${style('focus.transition')}s;
`;
```

In the current implementation it looks like this:

[displaying my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqSDm.png)

The bottom line is not fully displayed. How can I use CSS alone to make it so that only an integer number of lines (2 or 3) are displayed?
At the same time, the font size and line-height should not be changed.